# Three.js CSG library causes uncaught TypeError

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl, csg

I've started creating nice 3d objects with Three.js.
Now I'm trying to do a subtract as in the given example at:
https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/CSG.html
But I'm getting an error in the library:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ThreeCSG.js:215
window.ThreeBSP.ThreeBSP.toMesh                 ThreeCSG.js:215
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a quarter of a circle that a smaller circle is subtracted from it (so as to create the form of a bow).

Here's the plunkr.
http://plnkr.co/edit/lUxq0Oh1aXbRVd4c2rKG?p=preview

Any idea why the error is caused?

Comment: It is because ThreeCSG is not compatible with the version of three.js that you are using. Make sure both versions are compatible.

Comment: Thanks, how do I do that?

Comment: Ok, I've just downloaded the latest versions and it works.  Thanks :)